# Diagonalizing a given Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, fermions

The following Hamiltonian, which has to be diagonalized, is given:

> $H = \epsilon(f^{\dagger}_1f_1 + f_2^{\dagger}f_2)+\lambda(f_1^{\dagger}f_2^{\dagger}+f_1f_2)$

$f_i^{\dagger}$ and $f_i$ represent fermionic creation and annihiliation operators.
Right now I am not sure how to approach this problem. My idea is to use some kind of Bogoliubov transformation. I would be thankful for ideas on how to approach this problem.

Comment: The new fermionic operators are likely to be linear combinations of $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_1^{\dagger}$ and $f_2^{\dagger}$, where the transformation matrix should be unitary.  Just try something of the form $\alpha f_1 +\beta f_2 + \gamma  f_1^{\dagger} + \delta f_2^{\dagger}$, and figure out what the coefficients need to be in order for the new operators to fermionic (plug them into the commutation relations) and for the Hamiltonian to be diagonal (plug the new operators into the Hamiltonian and rearrange terms, looking for terms that must be zero).

Answer (score 4):

Since we have only two fermions creation operators, we are dealing with a finite dimensional system. In that case, I find that it is often easier to write out matrices and do algebra on those.

In the basis $(|00\rangle,|01\rangle,|10\rangle,|11\rangle)$ we have :
\begin{align}
f_1 &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
f_2 &= \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Therefore :
$$H = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0&0 & \lambda\\
0 & \epsilon & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & \epsilon &0 \\
\lambda & 0& 0 & 2\epsilon
\end{pmatrix}$$

The states $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$ are eigenstates with eigenvalue $\epsilon$.

On the orthogonal subspace, generated by $|00\rangle$ and $|11\rangle$, the induced Hamiltonian is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \lambda \\ \lambda & 2\epsilon \end{pmatrix} = \epsilon \mathbb I_2 + \lambda \sigma_x - \epsilon \sigma_z$. Therefore the eigenvalues are $\epsilon \pm \sqrt{\lambda^2 + \epsilon^2}$ and the eigenvectors are :
$$|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(\lambda^2+\epsilon^2 -\epsilon \sqrt{\epsilon^2 +\lambda^2}) }}\begin{pmatrix}-\epsilon + \sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \lambda^2} \\ \lambda\end{pmatrix} $$
and
$$|-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(\lambda^2+\epsilon^2 +\epsilon \sqrt{\epsilon^2 +\lambda^2}) }}\begin{pmatrix}-\epsilon - \sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \lambda^2} \\ \lambda\end{pmatrix} $$

In the basis $|01\rangle,|10\rangle,|+\rangle,|-\rangle$, we have :
$$H = \begin{pmatrix} \epsilon & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \epsilon &0 & 0\\
0& 0 & \epsilon+\sqrt{\lambda^2+\epsilon^2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0  & 0& \epsilon -\sqrt{\lambda^2 + \epsilon^2}\end{pmatrix}$$

To write this as a Bogoliubov transform, we remark that we can write $H = E_0 + E_1 ( c_1^\dagger c_1 + c_2^\dagger c_2)$, with $c_1$ and $c_2$ independent fermion annihilation operators, when :
\begin{align}
E_0 &= \epsilon \\
E_1 &= \sqrt{\lambda^2 + \epsilon^2}
\end{align}
and the eigenstates of $c_1^\dagger c_1$ and $c_2^\dagger c_2$ are :
\begin{align}
|00\rangle' &= |-\rangle \\
|01\rangle' &= |01\rangle\\
|10\rangle' &= |10\rangle\\
|11\rangle' &= |+\rangle
\end{align}
Solving for $c_1,c_2$ as linear combination of $f_1,f_2,f_1^\dagger,f_2^\dagger$ (as in a Bogoliubov transform), we get :
\begin{align}
c_1 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(\lambda^2+\epsilon^2 +\epsilon \sqrt{\epsilon^2 +\lambda^2}) }} \left( (-\epsilon -\sqrt{\epsilon^2+ \lambda^2})f_1 + \lambda f_2^\dagger\right) \\ &\qquad+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(\epsilon^2 + \lambda^2 - \epsilon\sqrt{\epsilon^2+ \lambda^2})}} \left( (-\epsilon +\sqrt{\epsilon^2+ \lambda^2})f_2 + \lambda f_1^\dagger\right) \\
c_2 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(\lambda^2+\epsilon^2 -\epsilon \sqrt{\epsilon^2 +\lambda^2}) }} \left( (-\epsilon + \sqrt{\epsilon^2+ \lambda^2})f_1 + \lambda f_2^\dagger\right) \\ &\qquad+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(\epsilon^2 + \lambda^2 + \epsilon\sqrt{\epsilon^2+ \lambda^2})}} \left( (-\epsilon -\sqrt{\epsilon^2+ \lambda^2})f_2 + \lambda f_1^\dagger\right) \\
\end{align}

There might be smarter/more efficient ways do perform the calculations, but this does the job.